# How to load the external css with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I load the external css file with jQuery but Google Page Speed says Eliminate  the blocking css.

index.html. I put the link to the library and the link to the javascript file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="general.js" defer ></script>
```

general.js. I load the css:

```
$(function(){
    $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />"); 
})
```

The css works well. But Google page speed still says 
Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content. Your page has 1 blocking CSS resources.https://www.example.com/style.css This causes a delay in rendering your page.

How should I use the link to the external css to have a good page speed and pass the Google Page Speed test?

Comment: Just add tye `<link>` directly into your `<head>` as usual. If you're really worried about 1 css file blocking rendering, you could put your "above-the-fold" css into a `<style>` tag.

Comment: Yes, but Google says I could link the NON above the fold css in a external css. How should I do that? the common link in the head is not accepted by the Google Page Speed.

Answer (score -1):

If you simply include the css file in the header like this:

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

does google speed still complain?

The blocking occurs because you are dynamically loading it with jQuery. On slower connections this could block the execution of the file (and your styles wouldn't be loaded).

If that doesn't help, you could still move the jQuery snippet right before the closing `</body>` of your page.
Not sure if google will accept that as a solution, but after all the page would load faster.

Comment: Pagespeed will still complain: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: And that's the downvote for? I still gave another solution. Btw the same as you gave, but mine is submitted as an answer, earlier than yours. Jealous?

Comment: 1- If I put the link to the stylesheet in the head Google complains. That is why I tried what I explain here. 2- If I put the jQuery code before the closing body tag, Google complains.